# VBA input a dynamic formula rather than just a value

Tags: vba, excel

I currenty have code that calculates the value of one cell divided by another and it works correctly.

How would I change it so that it would have the formula of that cell over the other, and hence update the value that I'm calculating when the two cells change values? e.g instead of "12"  it would be "B4 / D8".

The code is

```
For Tenant 1 to y
For Schedule = 1 To x

Sheet1.Cells(1782 + Tenant, 5 + x + Schedule).Value = (Sheet1.Cells(1782 + 
Tenant, 5 + Schedule).Value * Sheet1.Cells(1778, 8 + Schedule).Value)

Next Schedule
Next Tenant
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this outside a loop, but here's a simple conversion using your existing code:

```
For Tenant 1 to y
For Schedule = 1 To x

Sheet1.Cells(1782 + Tenant, 5 + x + Schedule).Formula = "=('" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & Sheet1.Cells(1782 + 
Tenant, 5 + Schedule).Address(0, 0) & "*'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" &  Sheet1.Cells(1778, 8 + Schedule).Address(0, 0) & ")"

Next Schedule
Next Tenant
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it better to do this function outside a loop?